# Exception unhandled SQL INTO

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently creating a sign in and out form and am trying to make the sign in part work this will link data from textboxes from a c# form to an SQL database

My question is: what is the syntax error in this system?

I currently get the message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.'

My code is:

```
 private void AcceptData()
    {
        using (Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            Connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("INPUT INTO Person", Connection))//this is currently where it says the error is
            {
                DataTable RegisterTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(RegisterTable); //System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.' TO FIX

                string name = textBox1.Text;
                string organisation = textBox3.Text;
                DateTime Time = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                string strDateTimeIn = Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff");
                string query = "INSERT INTO Person (Name,Organisation,TimeIn) VALUES('" + name + "','" + organisation + "','" + strDateTimeIn + "')";
                SqlCommand SignIn = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
                SignIn.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this should be fine currently

            }
        }

    }
```

Please help, thanks in advance Tom

Comment: Should be "Insert" instead of "INPUT " Also, if you are using data adapter and providing the query in the constructor then, you shouldn't need the additional "query" specified.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also `SqlDataAdapter` takes a select command.

Comment: @Terrance Cheers I'll do that now, Thanks pal

Comment: @Terrance I now get the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Person'.' any help?

Comment: @WMTS your sql statement is incomplete. If you inserting you will likely just need a sql command. Check this example and adapt it to your SqlCommand. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: First, you should use parameterized queries. Never concatenate strings to create an sql statement, since it's a security hazard (Read about SQL Injection). Second, 
You do not need to use `SqlDataAdapter`, you simply need to use `SqlCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled , thankyou I have added some edits could you please add an answer that shows this in detail if you wouldn't mind so I would be able to understand this further

Comment: Please learn the basics of the technology you intend to use before you start posting to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is (almost) how I would write it if I had to use ADO.Net only:

```
DateTime timeIn;
// I would rather use TryParseExact, I just don't know what format you expect...
if(DateTime.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out timeIn)) 
{
    using (var Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Person (Name,Organisation,TimeIn) VALUES(@Name, @Organisation, @TimeIn)";
        using(var SignIn = new SqlCommand(query, Connection))
        {
            SignIn.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            SignIn.Parameters.Add("@Organisation", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
            SignIn.Parameters.Add("@TimeIn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = timeIn;
            Connection.Open();
            SignIn.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this should be fine currently
        }
    }
}
```

With [ADONETHelper](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper) (a project I wrote you can download from GitHub) I would do it like this:

```
DateTime timeIn;
// Still prefer to use TryParseExact....
if(DateTime.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out timeIn))
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO Person (Name,Organisation,TimeIn) VALUES(@Name, @Organisation, @TimeIn)";
    var parameters = new IDbDataParameter[]
    {
        _DB.CreateParameter("@Name", ADONETType.NVarChar, textBox1.Text),
        _DB.CreateParameter("@Organisation", ADONETType.NVarChar, textBox3.Text),
        _DB.CreateParameter("@TimeIn", ADONETType.DateTime, timeIn)
    };
    _DB.ExecuteNonQuery(query, CommandType.Text, parameters);
}
```

Now in this case it only saves you 4 lines of code, but usually a single project contains many calls to the database - selecting, adding, editing and deleting records. This is when you see ADONETHelper's contribution - It saves you from a lot of code repetitions and encapsulate most of the ADO.Net plumbing for you.